# Using Grand Central Dispatch with infinite while loops?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, macos, parallel-processing, grand-central-dispatch

I have 5 functions that need to be run on a separate thread. Grand Central Dispatch is supposed to be more efficient than threads so I decided to use it. Each function has an infinite while loop - `while(true)`- that runs throughout the duration of the program. So the function doesn't return until the program exists. The thing is though, GCD doesn't run queues at the same time - it runs each queu one at a time. When the first queu completes, it begins the second queu. If I put each function on a queue, only one will run because Grand Central Dispatch will be waiting for the first one to return to run the next one but the function will never return (since it is an infinite while loop). Is there any way I can use GCD with infinite loop functions? Or should I just use threads?

Xcode 3.2.6 on Mac OSX Snowleopard 10.6.8.

Comment: Your 5 while() loops should (a) not be busy-waiting;  they should not  be looping unless they have real work to be done.  And (b), they shouldn't exist at all!  You should be using some other construct to wait for the work to be available.  Threads are expensive and wasteful.  Even idle threads waste resources.

Comment: @bbum My threads aren't busy waiting- they are continuously retrieving info and updating it. If threads are bad, do you have any other suggestions what I could use instead to continuously retrieve info throughout the duration of the program?

Comment: What is the data source?  I.e. network? Other threads? etc...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me like you are using dispatch_sync. Have a look at dispatch_async.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_async

It returns immediately, and you can launch multiple queues simultaneously, each function in a separate queue.

Comment: Dispatch_async still doesn't run parallel to each other

Comment: @Farhad Neo is correct and you are mistaken. Perhaps you are not dispatching async to a background queue?

Comment: @NJones From Apple: "It is important to remember that queues are not a panacea for replacing threads. The asynchronous programming model offered by queues is appropriate in situations where latency is not an issue. Even though queues offer ways to configure the execution priority of tasks in the queue, higher execution priorities do not guarantee the execution of tasks at specific times. Therefore, threads are still a more appropriate choice in cases where you need minimal latency, such as in audio and video playback."

Comment: @NJones Apple claims that GCD doesn't take latency into account - isn't this contradictory to what your saying?

Comment: @Farhad I said nothing of latency. I simply said that `dispatch_async()` does in fact run in parallel to the code that follows the `dispatch_async()` call (Provided it's dispatched to a different queue). For example if you call `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{/*background code here*/});` from an `IBAction` method (a method on the main thread) the code placed in the block will be queued to a background thread and any code placed after said call will begin immediately; Which is not so of the dispatch_sync call which will delay the following code until it completes.

Comment: Given the forgoing it is not hard to understand why one would think you were confusing the two dispatch methods.

Comment: @NJJones Thanks, that clears things up. Just confirming, dispatch_async runs the queu parallel to the calling thread, but only one queue runs at a time right? Because if all queues run at the same time, why would latency be an issue? Thanks again for your help, I'm just new to this and it's really confusing.

Comment: dispatch_async(), dispatch in general, is not really intended to have infinitely executing blocks enqueued.  Defeats the purpose.

Comment: @Farhad.. I am a bit unsure about Apple means by "latency", but I did look up the documentation (again), and confirmed that multiple queues can execute in PARALLEL (which is expected, and intuitive). So to answer your question, queues can run concurrently. 

https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW1

Comment: So all you have to do now is launch multiple queues, each with its own infinite loop, and use dispatch_async. 



Inspite of the perfectly valid concerns raised by other people regarding the use of infinite loops (which I agree with), I believe that you have good reason to try and do this, and that you have already researched and concluded that this is in fact the best way.

Answer (score 4):

Boy, lots of confused/conflciting answers so far!

First off, there is NO reason for you to use threads here.  None.  Using GCD, even for "long running" operations, is perfectly fine.  If all that you're doing from said operations is reading data and then doing something with the data then you should certainly use dispatch sources or dispatch_io since that's what they're for and they can greatly simplify your code, also only creating threads as necessary, but if you are really attached to the notion of having multiple, long-running parallel operations then simply wrap each of those operations into a block and then dispatch those blocks to one of the global concurrent queues.  They will run in parallel.  If what you have is more along the lines of "multiple workflows", in which each workflow represents a distinct chain of operations that need to happen serially but in parallel to the other workflows, then create a serial queue for each workflow and the independent serial queues will run concurrently with respect to one another.  It's just that simple!  GCD often confuses folks who are expecting things to be more complicated, or come from a classic threading background and trying to map one concept to the other.  Don't do that and you'll have a far easier time. :)

Answer (score 3):

The point of Grand Central Dispatch is to allow tasks that need to be executed asynchronously, but do not need a thread to run concurrently, can be efficiently queued without spawning additional threads.

However, if your function needs to execute continuously for the life of the program, you should continue to use threads: this is why they exist, and there are cases in which they are completely reasonable.

It is possible, however, that you can restructure your functions to not need an infinite loop (for instance, you might have your function invoke `dispatch_async` when it has completed its work, so that it will be scheduled to run again soon, or ideally, you would use GCD to have your function invoked only when something needs doing).

I can be more helpful if you specify what it is your functions do, and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks. I am creating an activity monitor like program, and my functions continuously retrieve stats (i.e processor usage, memory usage etc.). I want the data to be real time and continuous so I don't want to invoke it at certain every X seconds to update it. Do you have any other suggestions or would threads be my best option?

Comment: I wouldn't feel too bad about using threads (I feel worse about continuously querying stats, which will be pretty rough on system resources).

GCD could still work for you, if you want. If you have the function enqueue itself (or otherwise arrange for it to be put on the queue periodically), it won't run continuously, but whenever it comes up in the queue (which should be nearly continuously). This doesn't have to be "every second" (it can be much more frequent if you wish). Also keep in mind that threads do not run continuously either; they run at the pleasure of the scheduler.